# How to implement delete and move function using SwiftUI framework

Tags: swiftui

Not able to delete and move row at for the item in the list view.

Apple provided in their training video these methods but its not working

For removing:

```
array.remove(atOffsets: IndexSet)
```

For moving:

```
array.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet, toOffset: Int)
```

Both of these method are not available in the apple documentation.

[image: Simulator Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the methods you are refering to are now available on Xcode 11 GM. You can use them like this.

**removing an element**

TLDR:

```
.onDelete{offsets in
            self.array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
```

full code (can copy paste):
import SwiftUI

```
struct MyTableView : View {

@State var array=[1,2,3,4,5]

var body: some View {

    List{
        ForEach(array,id:\.self){element in
            Text("\(element)")
        }
        .onDelete{offsets in
            self.array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)

        }
    }

    }
}


struct MyTableView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTableView()
    }
}
```

**moving elements**

```
.onMove { (offsets, targetOffset) in
            self.array.move(fromOffsets: offsets, toOffset: targetOffset)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution... but I was specifically looking for apis related to   deleting at index using indexSet using method array.remove(atOffsets: IndexSet) and for move : array.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet, toOffset: Int). These method was introduced in WWDC 2019 Intro to SwiftUI. I couldn't find in my latest version of xcode 11.  BTW any work around to move item form one index to other.

Answer (score 4):

These methods are part of the Swift 5.1 standard library, which Apple will make available with a future beta of Xcode. In the meantime, you can use these extensions:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func remove(atOffsets offsets: IndexSet) {
        let suffixStart = halfStablePartition { index, _ in
            return offsets.contains(index)
        }
        removeSubrange(suffixStart...)
    }

    mutating func move(fromOffsets source: IndexSet, toOffset destination: Int) {
        let suffixStart = halfStablePartition { index, _ in
            return source.contains(index)
        }
        let suffix = self[suffixStart...]
        removeSubrange(suffixStart...)
        insert(contentsOf: suffix, at: destination)
    }

    mutating func halfStablePartition(isSuffixElement predicate: (Index, Element) -> Bool) -> Index {
        guard var i = firstIndex(where: predicate) else {
            return endIndex
        }

        var j = index(after: i)
        while j != endIndex {
            if !predicate(j, self[j]) {
                swapAt(i, j)
                formIndex(after: &i)
            }
            formIndex(after: &j)
        }
        return i
    }

    func firstIndex(where predicate: (Index, Element) -> Bool) -> Index? {
        for (index, element) in self.enumerated() {
            if predicate(index, element) {
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They either used custom extensions to Array or some version of Swift not available to the public yet.  Workarounds that I implemented are:

**delete**

```swift
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    if let first = offsets.first {
        store.rooms.remove(at: first)
    }
}
```

**move**

```swift
func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    if let first = source.first {
        store.rooms.swapAt(first, destination)
    }
}
```

Move function works however, the animation is not as good as the one on video at WWDC 2019.